# how to set bid modifier for demographic criteria like gender or age range

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

how to set bid modifier for demographic criteria like gender or age range?

I have already setup some of the basic operations found in google adwords sample code:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/basic-operations

I also manage to increase bid and decrease bid with Platform devices. But Ive been looking for age and gender, I haven't found it. Could someone give me an example on how to set bid modifier for demographic criteria for gender or age range. Thank you!

**Adding, updating and removing bid adjustments**

```
public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
    AdWordsSession $session, $adGroupId, $bidModifier) {
  $adGroupBidModifierService =
      $adWordsServices->get($session, AdGroupBidModifierService::class);

  $operations = [];

  // Mobile criterion ID.
  $criterionId = 30001;
  // Prepare to add an ad group level override.
  $adGroupBidModifier = new AdGroupBidModifier();
  $adGroupBidModifier->setAdGroupId($adGroupId);
  $adGroupBidModifier->setCriterion(new Platform());
  $adGroupBidModifier->getCriterion()->setId($criterionId);
  $adGroupBidModifier->setBidModifier($bidModifier);

  $operation = new AdGroupBidModifierOperation();

  // Create an ad group bid modifier operation and add it to the list.
  $operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
  $operation->setOperand($adGroupBidModifier);
  $operations[] = $operation;

  // Create the ad group bid modifier on the server and print out some
  // information for each created ad group criterion.
  $result = $adGroupBidModifierService->mutate($operations);
  foreach ($result->getValue() as $adGroupBidModifier) {
    printf(
        "Ad group ID %d, criterion ID %d was updated with "
            . "ad group level modifier: %s\n",
        $adGroupBidModifier->getAdGroupId(),
        $adGroupBidModifier->getCriterion()->getId(),
        $adGroupBidModifier->getBidModifier()
    );
  }
}
```

Now this code can be found in https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/bidding

This example does is increase and decrease with platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a forum where Google adwords developers will answer your question. I did some research on that forum, it looks like its already been answered.

Same question as you have with answer: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!searchin/adwords-api/bid$20on$20demographic$20criteria|sort:date/adwords-api/bq3ZjG8xbfI/l35zWdbiAwAJ

Quick view:

```
    $adGroupCriterionService = $adWordsServices->get($session, AdGroupCriterionService::class);
    $operations = [];

    $genderTarget = new Gender();
    $genderTarget->setId(10);
    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterion->setAdGroupId($adGroupId);
    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterion->setCriterion($genderTarget);
    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterion->setBidModifier(1.1);

    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterionOperation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterionOperation->setOperand($genderBiddableAdGroupCriterion);
    $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterionOperation->setOperator(Operator::SET);
    $operations[] = $genderBiddableAdGroupCriterionOperation;   

    $result = $adGroupCriterionService->mutate($operations);
```

Comment: This one works and Ill now continue on using this google forums. This one is really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Sure mate!.....